# Border to RadioButton with text in Android

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

In my application I want to give border to my Radio Button with text.

[image]

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioAndroid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@drawable/inout_radio_button"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/color_radio_text" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioiPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@drawable/inout_radio_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="@color/color_radio_text" />
```

I have put icon as below:

**inout_radio_button.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radioact" ></item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio" />
</selector>
```

But, i can't find way to give border around radio button.

Comment: Use parent layout and give it to border as drawable ad inside that you can set radio button !!!:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apply background parameter to the `RadioButton` directly (no need to surround it with external layout):

`android:background="@drawable/background"`

Where the background looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1px"
                android:color="@android:color/black"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Also apply the padding to the each of check mark images:

Inactive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/radio"
            android:left="6dp"
            android:right="6dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Active:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/radioact"
            android:left="6dp"
            android:right="6dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

And selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/active" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inactive" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: You mean something like: `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <layer-list >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/radioact" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:state_checked="true"/>
    </layer-list>
    <layer-list >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:state_checked="false" />
    </layer-list>
</selector>`

Comment: Close. But I think division of images and selector file is needed. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man,. You saved my life. Just there need only one `<layer-list>` in active and Inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Layout around your `RadioButton` and set a `backgroundDrawable` with a custom border

create `border.xml` and put it into `drawable`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and then use it in your `Layout`

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:background="@drawable/border">
  // your radiogroup
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It gives border to whole radio group. I want only for particular radio button

Comment: @ketan Well then put your background drawable directly into your `RadioButton`

Comment: then border will display above the text and icon. Can i give padding between border and icon